# how to hide/show a layout when recyclerview scroll (like twitter's new tweet layout)

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i want to add a layout which hides/shows when recyclerview scroll. that layout will hide when recyclerview scroll down, will show when recyclerview scroll up, like twitter's new tweet layout. i can do it for appbarlayout but i can not do for that layout. how can i do that?

http://i.hizliresim.com/rVyDq3.png

the purple layout will hide show like actionbar :

http://i.hizliresim.com/gAMp92.png

here is my layout file :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<!-- my main content -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/color_accent_pink">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/newsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <!-- that layout will hide/show when recyclerview scroll -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/takimlar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_group_item_swiping_active_state"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- my navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/merhabaText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Hello!"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found the answer there : https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/implement-floating-action-button-fab-part-2/

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

*I have a simple solution for that ..*

```
 recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onHide()
        {

            tabss.animate().translationY(tabss.getHeight())
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();      
           filtershow.animate().translationY(-filtershow.getHeight())
                  .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow()
        {
            tabss.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new
                    DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
         filtershow.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator
                 (new DecelerateInterpolator(1)).start();
        }
    });
```

*In that Recyclerview i was hiding screen top filters and screen bottom tabs*
*If you want have doubts about this hiding layout please ask me.*
*I will provide your required code for that.*

Comment: You might wanna add the HidingScrollListener code since its obviously a custom one.

Comment: I just applied animation in recycler view for filtershow named layout in my screen and tabbs is the another layout screen bottom.